# Excel VBA WorkSheet_Change Clear Contents If Blank

Tags: vba, excel

I'm setting a `Worksheet_Change` Macro so that if the contents of Cell K4 are not equal to "Event Based" the contents of J5:K7 are cleared. This works great. Code below.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim MRange As Range

    Set MRange = Range("K4")
    If MRange <> "Event Based" Then
       If Union(Target, MRange).Address = MRange.Address Then
           Application.EnableEvents = False
           Range("J5:K7").Select
           Selection.ClearContents
           Application.EnableEvents = True
       End If
    End If

End Sub
```

But I want a `Worksheet_Change` event if contents of cell J12 are cleared. But the below macro does NOT work. I know it is to do with cell value being empty, but I would appreciate any help.

```
    Dim NRange As Range

    Set NRange = Range("J12")
    If NRange = "" Then
        If Union(Target, NRange).Address = NRange.Address Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Range("J5:K7").Select
            Selection.ClearContents
            Application.EnableEvents = True

        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: see my answer below, let me know if that's what you meant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below checks if Cell J12 value has changed, if cell's value is "" then it clears the content of Range "J5:K7".

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim IntersectRange              As Range
    Dim NRange                      As Range

    Set NRange = Range("J12")
    Set IntersectRange = Intersect(Target, NRange)

    ' continue running this code only if Cell J12 has changed
    If Not IntersectRange Is Nothing Then

        If Target.Value = "" Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Range("J5:K7").ClearContents
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Shai - I knew it was something like that. This almost worked. When I ran I got an error at Target.Value = " " Then. I changed to NRange.Value = " " and it worked perfectly. I couldn't have gotten there without your help.